# Conditional text formatting for a link in Angular

Tags: html, angular, ionic-framework

I have an Angular 9 (Ionic) application which is localized. I need to add a checkbox where the user can accept the Terms and Conditions. The label should be a link (partially) where the Terms and conditions text should be underlined:

[image: I accept the Terms and conditions]

The text of the link should come from a json via a translate pipe. However as you can see in the picture above the order of the words can be different in each language. So I would avoid having two (or more) different entries for the separate parts. The best would be to somehow include the formatting inside my translation file, like so:

en.json:

```
{"Terms and Condition text": "I accept the _Terms and Conditions_"}
```

hu.json

```
{"Terms and Condition text": "_Általános Szerződési Feltételek_ elfogadása"}
```

Another option would be to have ***ngIf** or a **ngSwitchCase** for the supported languages but I find that solution very unprofessional.

Comment: What tool are you using for translation? You can probably just add the html to the json file and then add the translation using `innerHTML` like this: `<p [innerHTML]="'translation_key' | translate"></p>`

Comment: @tommueller Man, you are the best! It works as expected. Thank you very much! Too bad you didn't add it as an answer so I could accept it.

Comment: It is unsafe to use innerHTML. Because you can't be sure about the translated text is valid or invalid in HTML format. It can be innerText rather than innerHTML. Or you can use any other localization library like `ngx-translate` ...

Comment: @nevzatopcu I am using the @ngx-translate/core package but I couldn't find a way to control the look of the translated text. But if you have a suggestion for that I can definitely take another look. BTW the translation files are controlled by the dev team so having a valid html shouldn't be a problem.